# UITableView Crashing at count?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have my app have a simple TableView, and it was working all day yesterday. Now today when I tried to make it load another ViewController when a certain row is selected, it crashes before the TableView even comes up... so I commented out any new code I added and it's still crashing. The only thing xcode says as far as I can tell is it's breakpoint is at this method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [listOfSchools count];
}
```

Here's the rest of anything important.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Initialize the array.
    listOfSchools = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //Add items
    [listOfSchools addObject:@"CVHS"];
    [listOfSchools addObject:@"Elementary"];
    [listOfSchools addObject:@"Middle School"];
    [listOfSchools addObject:@"High School"];
    [listOfSchools addObject:@"All"];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Select Type of School";
    }
```

I don't understand why it's breaking. And no, this is NOT homework, just a project I'm helping out with at my school.

As always, thanks for your help.

Comment: show error that Xcode says in output, and try NSLog(@"%i",[listOfSchools count]); in viewDidLoad

Comment: and if it crashes after you selected row show us tableViewd:didSelectRowAtIndexPath code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out guys.

I somehow added manual breakpoints to like half the app? I don't understand how I did it, but once I found them and deleted them the app works fine now.

Thanks for the answers though!

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your array in the `-init` method rather than the `-viewDidLoad` method.